# Apache2 local virtual host doesn't work

Tags: server, xubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

I have a new installation of apache2 on ubuntu 20.04.02, but I have a problem with setting a localhosted virtual host:

In `/var/www/site.local/htdocs` I have my vhost folder.

Next I set in apache2.conf a `ServerName 127.0.0.1` variable.

Next in site available I copied 000-default.conf in site.local.conf in this way setted:

```
VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin perfetto@questionmark.it
ServerName test.local
ServerAlias www.test.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.local/htdocs 
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-access.log combined
```

Next I used `a2ensite site.local` then I restarted.

Finally I added the line in hosts file `test.local www.test.local   127.0.0.1`.

After all when in the browser search for my site doesn't work.

After running `apache2 -S` I have

```
VirtualHost configuration:
```

*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
default server 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost test.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.local.conf:1)
alias [www.test.local](http://www.test.local)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used

Someone can help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome. There is no Ubuntu 20. There is a 20.04 and a 20.10

Comment: Sorry 20.04.02...